# How does Linux choose when to update nohup?

Tags: unix, nohup

I need, for my work (I'm a Solid mechanics Phd Student) to use the nohup function. But my nohup.out isn't updated very often (about twice a day). So my question is:

How does it decides when to write data in the nohup.out, and is it possible to change the frequency of these updates?

Comment: if it is a script or command that is used to update, you can make a cronjob to call that script as often as you would like

Comment: agree that crontab entry may be a better approach. Else, your problem is likely that output is buffered. Try changing some/any/all cmds that produce output  to be prefixed like `unbuffer nohup myscript > log.txt` or `noh unb sc > lg`. Its never clear to me the "span of control" for unbuffer, so you may have to apply `unbuffer` to program calls inside your `myscript`. Also, you may have to look around to find `unbuffer`. It often is installed in a non-standard PATH dir. If no results from `which unbuffer`, then run `find /usr -name unbuffer` (and wait a while ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i'm going to try that

Comment: Ok, as you said I have had troubles finding unbuffer, in fact, I think that this command isn't installed on the calculation server of my laboratory. But thanks to your answer, I managed to find (by trying to find some information aobut unbuffer) the stdbuf command and to have the nohup updated line by line (stdbuf -oL nohup craft -v &). So thanks a lot, and have a good day :)

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ is probably a better solution so there's no buffering and it will not hangup on disconnect

Comment: thanks @BorisBurgarella for the nice solution!